# Configure SWRevealViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a found many tutorials on how to configure [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) via storyboards, but I am looking to move away from storyboards and xibs altogether.

So I was wondering, is there a way to configure the library programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

There are sample projects in the SWReveal package that you downloaded. They are all implemented programmatically if I remember correctly.

From the AppDelegate.m of sample project #2:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;

    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
        initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;

    self.viewController = mainRevealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
    let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
    let rearNavigationController:UINavigationController
    let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
    var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

    let sidebar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "sidebarMenuVCID")as! sidebarMenu

    let homepage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageVCID") as! HomePage

    frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: homepage)
    rearNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sidebar)

    revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
    revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController
    revealController.delegate = self
    mainRevealController  = revealController

    self.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
```

Comment: I didn't know semicolons returned in Swift 3! Shucks! I never liked those

Comment: Done this  please check

Answer (score 0):

Update for Swift 5.x (Programmatically)

From AppDelegate, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
    var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

    let sidebar = SideBarViewController()
    let homepage = ViewController()

    let frontNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homepage)
    let rearNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sidebar)

    revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
    revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController
    revealController.delegate = self

    mainRevealController  = revealController

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController

    return true
```